# Bricks with an axle hole

Tags: piece-information

I'm looking for bricks/elements with an axle hole in it "sideways". I.e. so the axle hole direction is perpendicular to the stud direction.
The [1x1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=73230) and [1x2](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32064) technic bricks are obvious, but besides that, I can find only one other brick which seems to me pretty rare/exotic. I thought there were more.

Comment: Can you include the name of the "one other brick" in your question so that other people don't suggest it as an answer?

Gotta say though, I just did a quick scan in BL and I think you might be right. Would it be worth mentioning some simple two part combinations that might satisfy your requirements? (ForEx: Combine [Technic, Brick Modified 2 x 2 with Ball Socket and Axle Hole (62712)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=62712) or it's several variants with [Technic Ball Joint with Through Axle Hole (53585)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=53585)

Comment: Most connector pieces with axle holes have no orientation - ie. they can be oriented however you prefer - including with the axle hole sideways. I suspect that's not what you're after, and you're looking for parts that have both studs and an axle hole  (sideways) ?

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to nominate the following pieces:

- [Propeller Housing](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6040#T=C)

[image: Propeller Housing]

- [Brick, Modified 2 x 4 x 2 with Holes on Sides](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6061#T=C)

[image: Brick, Modified 2 x 4 x 2 with Holes on Sides]

- [Brick, Modified Octagonal 2 x 2 x 3 1/3 with Side Studs](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6042&idColor=3#T=C&C=3)

[image: Brick, Modified Octagonal 2 x 2 x 3 1/3 with Side Studs]

They all have axle holes that are perpendicular to some of their studs.

Comment: Some more : [Plate, Modified 2 x 2 with Pin Hole on Side and Axle Hole on Bottom](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15108), [Projectile Launcher, 2 x 4 with 5 Studs, Axle Hole and Pin Lever](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=61185c01), [Technic, Brick Modified 2 x 2 with Axle Hole, Rotation Joint Ball Half Vertical, and Fist](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=47431), [Technic, Brick 2 x 4 x 1 1/3 with Axle Holes and 2 x 2 Cutout](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=67446)

Comment: The picture of part 6061 does not show that it has axle holes.  Does anyone have a better picture of that?

Comment: @chicks : just took a picture of one (lighting not ideal, but should be good enough to show these indeed have axle holes) : https://i.stack.imgur.com/goMei.jpg

Comment: @SanderDeDycker If you were to add this list as a separate answer, I'd gladly upvote it for the list of exotic parts it contains.

Comment: @zovits : I didn't add another answer because I don't feel it would improve on the answers already provided. The parts I listed are either so rare/specific they're unlikely to be useful for the op's purposes, or are a variation of a part already included in an answer. Iow - I didn't want to confuse the matter with a third answer. Feel free to include the parts in your answer if you think there's value in it.

Comment: @Sander, the purpose I have in mind is very specific so I didn't bother including it in my question. However, I think a complete list of stuff with axle holes in it (and searching in bricklink seems to miss most of the ones listed here) even though the elements are exotic would be of general use. I have no strong opinion wheter that list should be an additional answer or Zovits answer should be expanded.

Comment: Since there seems to be a consensus an additional answer is not a problem, I've added one to help complete the list.

Answer (score 5):

- [Bar 1 x 8 with Brick 1 x 2 Curved Top End (Axle Holder Inside Small End)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30359b)

[image]

- [Technic, Brick 2 x 6 x 1 1/3 with Axle Holes and Bottom Stud Holders](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3668) (and its [lightweight variant](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=65635))

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Since a few people have expressed they wouldn't mind an additional answer, here are some more parts to add to the list, without expectation that they're going to be particularly useful to the OP.

Some rare/exotic parts :

[Plate, Modified 2 x 2 with Pin Hole on Side and Axle Hole on Bottom](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15108) :

[image]

[Projectile Launcher, 2 x 4 with 5 Studs, Axle Hole and Pin Lever](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=61185c01) :

[image]

[Technic, Brick Modified 2 x 2 with Axle Hole, Rotation Joint Ball Half Vertical, and Fist](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=47431) :

[image]

And finally also a variation of a part from [@IvanSanchez' answer](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/18407/19372) (simply added for completeness) :

[Technic, Brick 2 x 4 x 1 1/3 with Axle Holes and 2 x 2 Cutout](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=67446) :

[image]